# How to use datatables on Codeigniter (especially for making the search box)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

Well, before i get started, im sorry for bad english yet my little knowledge in programming especially on codeigniter that i've been working on 2 weeks.

then i found the datatables. i found it interesting if i can integrate--or anything you guys called it-- the datatables with the codeigniter.

i downloaded the ignited-datatables, attached it, and yet it still not working on my project.

some help please? im new to codeigniter and datatables. i'll appreciate all of the answers, though.

P.S : just ask it if you guys need the code, i'll show you ;)

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know [www.datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net)?
You can include javascript & css (local installation):

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js') ?>"></script>

<!-- DataTables JS -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') ?>"></script>
```

Then, inside your table:

```
<table id="dataTables-example"> ...</table>
```

Finally, the script:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable();
} );
```

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you already have a running database.
For the example, let's suppose that we have a table named "cars" containing a list of cars and their specifities.

```
cars :
  id    |  brand  | model  | year
   1    |  Ford   | Escort | 1989
   2    |  Audi   | A4     | 2005
  ...   |  ...    | ...    | ...
```

How it works on codeigniter :

### 1/ Configuration file

---

Set your database connection values in *application/config/database.php*.

Here we are setting a connection to our local server for the database "mydatabase". Login/password are myusername/mypassword.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'myusername',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'database' => 'mydatabase',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'autoinit' => TRUE,
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

More details here : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

### 2/ Models

---

Codeigniter is a MVC framework. It means that you must separate database (Models) access from what you display (Views) or any other treatment (Controllers). 
In *application/models/* we create a new model named Cars.php :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cars extends CI_Model
{   
}
```

Inside our new class, we are going to write a function that gets all the cars in the table. 
CodeIgniter uses an ORM called Active Record. To summarize, it's a tool that makes query writing easier and safier.

```
public function getAllCars()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('cars');
    //This how you write *SELECT * FROM cars* with Active Record

    return $query->result(); //The result is an array of objects, each row = an object
}
```

More details : 
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

### 3/ Controller

---

Now, we need to create a new controller. So in *application/controllers* make a new file named Cars.php :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cars extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {

    }

}
```

Inside our new controller we are going to call our model.

```
public function index()
{
    //First we need to load the model
    $this->load->model('cars');

    //Now we need to get our car list using the function we write on our model
    $car_list = $this->cars->getAllCars();

   //Finally, we send are list to the view so we can display it.
   $data["cars_lst"] = $car_list;
   $this->load->view("mycars", $data); //We are building this view in the next step.
}
```

More details : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

### 4/ View

---

Final step, the output. In *application/views/* create a new file mycars.php.
Keep in mind that in our controller, we called that view and sent to it an array with our car_list at the index "car_lst".
We now can use that array index as a var in our view which will contains our list of cars (remember the model result ?).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
         <!-- Meta, title, CSS, ... -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <table class="table table-hover">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Id</th>
                     <th>Brand</th>
                     <th>Model</th>
                     <th>Year</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>

             <?php foreach ($car_lst as $c): ?>

             <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $c->id; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $c->brand; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $c->model; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $c->model; ?></td>              
             </tr>

             <?php endforeach; ?>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

### 5/ Voilà !

---

Now if we access our application with *http://localhost/mysite/index.php/cars/* we should see our cars list.

This is how to deal with database in codeigniter. Of course it's a light preview but you should be able to understand how it works and find your own solutions.

Comment: Well, thank you though, but i got it already._.v
what makes me confused is only how to put the datatables to the codeigniter.

Comment: What do you mean by datatables ?

Comment: see the question first. your answer is not question specific. @AdrienXL

Comment: @AvnishTiwary Thanks for pointing that out almost 2 years later :/

Answer (score 0):

I know the question has been answered but this might be helpful to others as well.

If you want to use pure javascript library (no jQuery dependency), you could use **[Vanilla-DataTables](https://github.com/Mobius1/Vanilla-DataTables)**

To use:

Add these into your main file

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-datatables@latest/dist/vanilla-dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-datatables@latest/dist/vanilla-dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then on your js file just add:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable("#table_list"); //where #table_list is the id of your table
```

There are also a lot of [Options](https://github.com/Mobius1/Vanilla-DataTables/wiki/Options) available applicable to your choice

Or if you want newer library, you could also check on [Simple-DataTables](https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables)

Hope this helps.